# Ошибка доступа при логине

Tags: c++

```
struct account{
    char  login[255];
    char  pass[255];
    char  name[255];
    char  category[255];
};      
int accn=0; 
account    * pacc;
account * npacc;
char cin[255]; //ввод  командной строки 

void addacc(){
    accn++;
    pacc=(account*)realloc(pacc, sizeof(account)*accn);
    npacc=pacc+sizeof(account)*(accn-1);   
    printf("Enter login: "); scanf("%s", &cin); memcpy(&(npacc->login), &cin, 255);
    printf("Enter password: "); scanf("%s", &cin); memcpy(&(npacc->pass), &cin, 255);
    printf("Enter name: "); scanf("%s", &cin); memcpy(&(npacc->name), &cin, 255);
    printf("Enter category name: "); scanf("%s", &cin); memcpy(&(npacc->category), &cin, 255);
    printf("Done!"); enter;

};
```

При первом вызове `addacc()` все проходит успешно. При втором выдаёт ошибку после ввода логина.

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что пишете на с++?

Comment: @KoVadim, первый раз. Что не так?

Comment: это не плюсы, это чистый с. А ошибка в строке

    npacc=pacc+sizeof(account)*(accn-1);

при втором элементе оно будет выходить далеко за пределы. pacc - это массив указателей. Здесь скорее всего нужно писать просто

    npacc=pacc[accn-1];

Comment: @KoVadim, поясните про чистый с.

Comment: @KoVadim, а почему это массив, я не понял. Объявлено же просто как указатель

Comment: в вышеприведенном коде не используются возможности с++.  если бы этот код я писал на плюсах, то у меня был бы `std::vector<account>` для начала.

Хотя все же, одну возможность плюсов Вы используете - это `sizeof(account)`. На с пришлось бы писать `sizeof(struct account)`.

В с указатель и массив  очень родственные души. Иногда разница между ними только в голове у программиста.

Comment: @KoVadim, я правильно понял, что если я прибавляю к pacc 1, то прибавляется не 1 байт, а размер account'a?

Comment: нет. добавляется `sizeof(account    *)` (звездочку видите?). А это скорее всего 4 байта или 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке

```
npacc=pacc+sizeof(account)*(accn-1);
```

у вас работает арифметика указателей.

К примеру...

```
int A;
int *P = &A;
```

Предположим что переменная А находится по адресу 0.
тогда сделав

```
P = P + 1;
```

мы получим адрес 4 так как переменная А занимает 4 байта.

А вы берете указатель на структуру и увеличиваете не на 1 что бы перейти к следующей структуре, а на размер структуры. а у неё размер больше 1024байт и поэтому вы в итоге обращаетесь к памяти которая находится на 1024 структуры дальше.

короче я наверно так хорошо вам не объясню, почитайте книжку по С или С++ про арефметику указателей и вам все станет ясно.

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, спасибо, понял

Comment: ох, если А находиться по адресу 0... то желательно этот компилятор выбросить.

Answer (score 3):

[[@ололо](/users/4501/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE)](/users/4501/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE), а зачем Вы лишние операции `&` пишите? Между прочим, компилятор будет ругаться (warning-ом). Да и выталкивать (fflush) вывод в приглашении и проверять ввод на конец файла не помешает.

Попробуйте что-то в духе

```
#define enter(prompt,field) (fputs((prompt), stdout), fflush(stdout),   \
                             scanf("%s", (field)))

int addacc(){
    pacc=(account*)realloc(pacc, sizeof(account) * ++accn);
    npacc = pacc + accn - 1;

   int rc = 1;
   if (enter("Enter login: ", npacc->login) != 1 ||
       enter("Enter password: ", npacc->pass) != 1 ||
       enter("Enter name: ", npacc->name) != 1 ||
       enter("Enter category name: ", npacc->category) != 1) {
     --accn;
     rc = 0;
   }

  return rc;
}
....
main () {
...
  while (addacc())
    printf ("account %d : %s %s %s %s\n", accn, pacc[accn-1].login, "", "", "");
...
}
```

В GNU есть нестандартное расширение, позволяющее "безопасно" читать scanf()-ом по формату %s (см.. man 3 fscanf). Используя его, макрос для ввода поля даннных с заданной максимальной длиной этого поля, можно переписать так (и лучше в виде статической функции)

```
static inline int  enter(const char *prompt, char *field, int size) 
{
  char *buf; int rc;
  fputs(prompt, stdout); fflush(stdout);
  *field = 0;

  if ((rc = scanf("%as", &buf)) == 1) {
    strncat(field, buf, size);
    free(buf);
  } else 
    rc = 0;

  return rc; 
}
```